# Scrollbar covers text in right cell

Tags: html

I am truly stuck on this problem

My table has three cells across (no header) - When I add a scrollbar to the table, the table keeps its width so the scrollbar actually takes part of the right hand cell and covers the border. I don't care if the table is a little bigger or smaller but I want the entire contents of the table with 3 equal cells and the border too. The scrollbar should be attached to the table, not hiding the content

I've looked everywhere and tried everything

Here is my code

```
<table class="aligncenter" width = "500" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #6b1ae4; background-color: #cfdfee;" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
<tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>cell #1a...............</td>
```

I now tried using the example in http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/ but I am getting the same problem

Comment: NEVERMIND - I FOUND A SOLUTION

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/1054/). Is this want you want

Your css looks like this

```
#table-wrapper {
  position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
#table-scroll {
  height:100px;   
}
#table-wrapper table {
  width:100%;
}
#table-wrapper table * {
  background:yellow;
  color:black;
}
#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
  position:absolute;   
  z-index:2;
  height:20px;
  width:33%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle wasn't good for me since I wanted different background colors (checkerboard) for the cells - There must be a way to do that but I couldn't find it

This is what finally worked for me

```
<div style="padding: 1px; height: 500px;width: 775px;  overflow: auto;">
<table class="aligncenter" width = "755" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #6b1ae4; background-color: #cfdfee;" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
```

The diffence in the width did it